# JavaScript move object by button by X px

Tags: javascript, button, move, moving-average

How am i supposed to move object by button by (in this case) 10px? In my code right and down button doesnt work, up and left move image, but not by 10px, to the top / left edge.
I tried this:

Comment: Hi PoloOlo, are you trying to move the object 10 pixels from the element's original position or 10 pixel from the left side of the screen?

Comment: Hi @Ivan, thank you for the response. I'm trying to move it from original position (which is specified in style, object position is absolute), in case of few clicks I want it to be moving from place, where it was moved before

Comment: @PoloOlo, your original question was more descriptive also included what you tried. But this type of question is not encouraged in SO, so I suggest you re-post your original question or include what you tried in here.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that your picture is not positioned, meaning it's positioned `static` by default, so you cannot use left, right, top, or bottom styling properties. I have set the parents positioning to `relative` and the child's(img) position to `absolute` so that the positioning of the image will be relative to the parent( the body in your case).

I think you also want to do incremental assignment on every button click, in which case you should get the current position of the image first. You can do that with `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` properties.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>  

    <img onclick="A()" id='inspo' src="a8.jpg">

    <button id="left" onclick="moveleft()">left</button>
    <button class="right" onclick="moveright()">right</button>
    <button class="down" onclick="movedown()">down</button>
    <button class="up" onclick="moveup()">up</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function moveleft() {
  const img = document.getElementById('inspo');
  img.style.left = `${img.offsetLeft - 10}px`;
}

function moveright() {
  const img = document.getElementById('inspo');
  img.style.left = `${img.offsetLeft + 10}px`;
}

function moveup() {
  const img = document.getElementById('inspo');
  img.style.top = `${img.offsetTop - 10}px`;
}

function movedown() {
  const img = document.getElementById('inspo');
  img.style.top = `${img.offsetTop + 10}px`;
}


function A() {
  document.getElementById('inspo').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</body>
```

EDIT:
If you want to keep your original styling and use `left` and `top` properties to not only set values but also get values, you could use the below code, note that `left` and `top` properties return string so you will have to convert the result to number before doing arithmetic operation on it.

```html
<body style="position: relative;">  

    <img style=" position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px;" onclick="A()" id='inspo' src="a8.jpg">

    <button id="left" onclick="moveleft()">left</button>
    <button class="right" onclick="moveright()">right</button>
    <button class="down" onclick="movedown()">down</button>
    <button class="up" onclick="moveup()">up</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function moveleft() {
  const img = document.getElementById('inspo');
  img.style.left = Number(img.style.left.slice(0, -2)) - 10 + 'px';
}

function moveright() {
  const img = document.getElementById('inspo');
  img.style.left = Number(img.style.left.slice(0, -2)) + 10 + 'px';
}

function moveup() {
  const img = document.getElementById('inspo');
  img.style.top = Number(img.style.top.slice(0, -2)) - 10 + 'px';
}

function movedown() {
  const img = document.getElementById('inspo');
  img.style.top = Number(img.style.top.slice(0, -2)) + 10 + 'px';
}


function A() {
  document.getElementById('inspo').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 75px;
      background-color: red;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    #div2 {
      transform: rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
      /* IE 9 */
      -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
      /* Firefox */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
      /* Safari and Chrome */
      -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
      /* Opera */
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p onclick="A()" id='inspo' src="a8.jpg">OK</p>

  <button id="left" onclick="moveleft()">left</button>
  <button class="right" onclick="moveright()">right</button>
  <button class="down" onclick="movedown()">down</button>
  <button class="up" onclick="moveup()">up</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var topNum = 0,
      leftNum = 0;

    function moveleft() {
      leftNum -= 10;
      document.getElementById('inspo').style.marginLeft = leftNum + 'px';
    }

    function moveright() {
      leftNum += 10;
      document.getElementById('inspo').style.marginLeft = leftNum + 'px';
    }

    function moveup() {
      topNum -= 10;
      document.getElementById('inspo').style.marginTop = topNum + 'px';
    }

    function movedown() {
      topNum += 10;
      document.getElementById('inspo').style.marginTop = topNum + 'px';
    }


    function A() {
      document.getElementById('inspo').style.display = "none";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```